# Matlab implicit plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, waveform

How can I plot a curve between *h/L* and *h/L0* from the following equation:

[image: equation]

> [(h/L){((Dk^4/g) + 1)tanh(kh)}]^(1/2) = (h/L0)^(1/2){1-(TU/h)(h/L)}

I tried it myself but I am not able to get the right curve. My code was as follows:

```
D=10^11;
g=9.8;
T=1;
U=5;
h=1;
a=T*U/h;
L= (-3:0.01:3);
L0=(-3:0.01:3);
y=h./L;
x=h./L0;
k=(2*pi/h).*y;
y= (x.*(1-a.*y).^2)./(((16*D*(pi^4)*(y.^4)/(g*h^4))+1).*tanh(2*pi.*y));
plot(x,y,'b');
xlabel('h/L0');
ylabel('h/L');
```

Here `g` is acceleration due to gravity and `k` is wave number. `D` is the rigidity factor and is equal to *D = EI/d* where *d* is the density and *EI* is the rigidity and *k = 2pi/L*.

Comment: Also, Im not sure if that equation is "doable". You want to plot h/Lo vs h/L, but what about that h that sits alone inside tanh?

Comment: the h that sits along tanh is not the h we are given here and that h will not effect this h. tanh is a standard function and hopefully, that will not effect this.

Comment: not this h, `tanh<-` but this one `tanh(kh<-`. if that h inside is different than the outside, then the equation is not properly expressed, it sould be a different symbol.

Comment: for that h, we can express it as kh = (2pi/L)*h = 2pi(h/L) = 2pi*y

Comment: I see. Can you please, state all the mathematical equalities *outside the code* please? your code is quite wrong, but I am unable to fix it unles sI understand the equation properly. However, the kh= 2pi(h/L) relatioship  is nowhere outside the code explained